# How multi correlated query works with Join

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

I'm struggling to understand below query

```
INSERT INTO PAT_INT
SELECT SRC.SK ,
SRC.PHONE_NO,
SRC.NAME,
to_date(now()),
NULL,
1
FROM PAT_LOAD src
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1                       //1st part
                 FROM PAT_INT INT1
                 WHERE src.sk = INT1.sk
                 AND flag = 0
                 AND NOT EXISTS
                                 (SELECT 1                     //2nd part
                                    FROM PAT_INT INT2
                                    WHERE INT1.sk = INT2.sk
                                    AND flag = 1 )
            );
```

`PAT_LOAD` is source table

`PAT_INT`  is intermediate table

record is active when flag is 1 and 0 for in-active

This query is being used to get updated records from source table.

problem

Am not able to understand the flow of sql query

here is my understanding below steps wise.

1. 1 record comes from outermost query
2. Then it joins with 1st part of query
3. the match found in 2nd step looked into output of join between (`1st part of query and 2nd part of query`)

Is it correct ? or am understanding it wrong ?

```
Doubt
```

First trying to get match with all not-active (`flag is 0`) records, then out of those records its looking for Ids which don't exists in active state.

What's is being achieved here ?

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct.

Comment: @TheImpaler, can you please share how EXISTS and NOT EXISTS part is working in above query ?

Comment: For every row in `PAT_LOAD` it verifies there's at least one row in `PAT_INT` with flag = 0 -- that in itself does not have a related row in the same table with flag = 1. It goes by levels as you described.

Comment: @TheImpaler, can you please look my updated doubt in question ?

Comment: Seems like the query is looking for inactive records (flag = 0) that have never been active. Anyway, it's not easy to tell without some sample data.